# Cannot launch Viber on elementary OS freya

Tags: software-installation, appcenter

After removing Viber version 5 from software center, and with

```
sudo dpkg --purge viber
sudo apt-get remove viber
```

I downloaded the version 6 viber `.deb` file from Viber's website, opened it and installed it with software center.
When trying to launch Viber I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep3D9.png).
And by running

```
/opt/viber/QtWebEngineProcess
```

in terminal, i get

> [0425/170521:FATAL:browser_main_loop.cc(161)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

update:
By running:

```
opt/viber/Viber
```

in terminal i get:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".
>
> Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>   Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5gui5
```

Run this in terminal and then reinstall viber.deb
This resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I never use software center for installation, so I do not know how it handles `.deb` files. But maybe `gdebi` can help you:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdebi
$ sudo gdebi viber6-XXX.deb
```

This will install all related dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For those who prefer to solve issues from the command line, simply run:

`sudo apt-get install -f`

...whenever a deb you've installed didn't have its dependencies resolved.